# Why is KernelEvents::TERMINATE blocking the response to the user?

Tags: php, events, event-handling, silex, hhvm

In a Silex application running on HVVM I have setup a dummy event listener on Kernel `TERMINATE`:

```
$app['dispatcher']->addListener(
    KernelEvents::TERMINATE,
    function () use ($app) {
        usleep(10000000);
        $app['logger']->alert("I AM REGISTERED!");
    }
);
```

I was expecting my application to render the response as fast as possible within a second and after 10s I expected the message `"I AM REGISTERED"` to appear in my log.

Yet strangely the response is sent after the event has been executed, meaning the event blocks the response for 10s and I see both the response and the log message at the same time.

What is going on here?

I find it odd that in the Application.php, it appears that `send` is called before `terminate`:

`vendor/silex/silex/src/Silex/Application.php`:

```
/**
 * Handles the request and delivers the response.
 *
 * @param Request|null $request Request to process
 */
public function run(Request $request = null)
{
    if (null === $request) {
        $request = Request::createFromGlobals();
    }

    $response = $this->handle($request);
    $response->send();
    $this->terminate($request, $response);
}
```

Comment: PHP isn't asynchronous. When you tell it to `sleep`, it will just stop doing _anything_ until that has finished. If you need to do things asynchronously, you need to use a cron or a queuing service like AMPQ.

Comment: It's also likely that the framework builds the entire response first, and then sends it as it's last step (in case there are any headers to be sent, or re-directs to happen - it can't send any more headers to the browser once the content ha started flowing).

Comment: @samlev From what I gather, the terminate should be executed after the send; see updated question

Comment: Currently researching: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_kernel/introduction.html: "Internally, the HttpKernel makes use of the fastcgi_finish_request PHP function. This means that at the moment, only the PHP FPM server API is able to send a response to the client while the server's PHP process still performs some tasks. With all other server APIs, listeners to kernel.terminate are still executed, but the response is not sent to the client until they are all completed."

Comment: There might be a workaround: https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/issues/1230

Answer (score 1):

The [symfony2 docs about `HttpKernel`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_kernel/introduction.html), which silex is uisng as well, it says:

> Internally, the HttpKernel makes use of the fastcgi_finish_request PHP
>   function. This means that at the moment, only the PHP FPM server API
>   is able to send a response to the client while the server's PHP
>   process still performs some tasks. With all other server APIs,
>   listeners to kernel.terminate are still executed, but the response is
>   not sent to the client until they are all completed.

And `fastcgi_finish_request` is [not currently supported by hhvm](http://docs.hhvm.com/manual/en/function.fastcgi-finish-request.php).

Hence, the response will not be sent unless all events are completed.

Answer (score 1):

1. PHP is not asynchronous, so while event handling is possible through use of callbacks, as soon as the event triggers, the control flow of the process will be dedicated to it.
2. Frameworks tend to delay content response to be the last action taken, in case any form of header modification has to happen.

As you mentioned, the content is being sent/echoed before the `TERMINATE` event is fired, but that's not the whole story.

It depends on how your server is set up. If, for example, you have gzip enabled in apache (very common), then *apache* will cache all content until PHP has finished execution (and then it will gzip and send it). You mentioned that you're on HHVM, which could also be the problem - it might not flush the content itself until execution is complete.

Either way, the best solution is to... well... not sleep. I'm assuming that you're sleeping to give the database a chance to flush to disk (10 seconds is a really long time to wait for that, though). If that's not the case, then finding a decent solution won't be easy until we can understand *why* you need to wait that long.

Comment: The sleep was just a dummy-code to test my theory about the behaviour of the event. The actual payload is something minor (sending a bunch of http requests to an api) yet I wanted to avoid having the user wait for that process to complete. My goal was to have some code being executed after the response has been sent, what kind of code was purely arbitrary.

Comment: You could move those processes off-band if they're long running and not time-sensitive (add them into a queue, then process the queue with a cron, or send them to a message queue, which will farm them out to workers). Of course this won't work if these things have to be done before the user can continue. If you want the user to know things are happening, try doing this process in an ajax call, and have a UI spinner telling them to wait.

Comment: @k0pernikus take a look at [RabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-php.html).

Comment: The irony is that I want to send messages in the background to a kafka queue. It feels weird to use a queue to fill a queue.

Comment: If they take a long time to send, but are relatively predictable, then it may be worth off-banding them (waiting for one API call is better than 3 or 6 or whatever). If they don't take long, then the user may not notice a few more ms on the response. You could also fire it earlier instead of on process termination.

Comment: Yes, currently I just have to deal with the slight overhead of waiting for a bunch of api calls. Currently, they are not taking that long that it would hinder the application, so this whole feature is currently a nice to have and not mandatory. Still, from a technical point of view quite a bummer.

Comment: Other things to consider: depending on server set up, if you *did* get the content back to the user quickly, and then they navigated to another page, the server could kill that connection before it finishes processing.