# Does hvvm work with fastcgi_finish_request?

Tags: php, fastcgi, hhvm

As a follow-up question on getting [KernelEvents::TERMINATE to not block the response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34002455/why-is-kerneleventsterminate-blocking-the-response-to-the-user), I am now wondering if hhvm supports `fastcgi-finish-request`.

Is it supported, and if so, how do I enable it?

Comment: Possible workarounds: https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/issues/1230

Answer (score 1):

No, [it is not supported](http://docs.hhvm.com/manual/en/function.fastcgi-finish-request.php):

> fastcgi_finish_request
>
> (PHP 5 >= 5.3.3) fastcgi_finish_request — Flushes all response data to
>   the client
>
> NOT SUPPORTED IN HHVM